# OpenCL 2.x - Sum Reduction function

Tags: sum, opencl, macos-high-sierra, reduction

From this previous post: [strategy-for-doing-final-reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879187/strategy-for-doing-final-reduction), I would like to know **the last functionalities offered by OpenCL 2.x** (not 1.x which is the subject of this previous post above), especially about the atomic functions which allow to perform reductions of a array (in my case a sum reduction).

One told me that performances of OpenCL 1.x atomic functions (`atom_add`) were bad and I could check it, so I am looking for a way to get the best performances for a `final reduction function` (i.e the sum of each computed sum corresponding to each work-group).

I recall the typical kind of kernel code that I am using for the moment :

```
__kernel void sumGPU ( __global const double *input, 
                       __global double *partialSums,
               __local double *localSums)
 {
  uint local_id = get_local_id(0);
  uint group_size = get_local_size(0);

  // Copy from global memory to local memory
  localSums[local_id] = input[get_global_id(0)];

  // Loop for computing localSums
  for (uint stride = group_size/2; stride>0; stride /=2)
     {
      // Waiting for each 2x2 addition into given workgroup
      barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

      // Divide WorkGroup into 2 parts and add elements 2 by 2
      // between local_id and local_id + stride
      if (local_id < stride)
        localSums[local_id] += localSums[local_id + stride];
     }

  // Write result into partialSums[nWorkGroups]
  if (local_id == 0)
    partialSums[get_group_id(0)] = localSums[0];
 }
```

As you can see, at the end of kernel code execution, I get the array `partialSums[number_of_workgroups]` containing all partial sums.

Could you tell me please how to perform a second and final reduction of this array, with the best performances possibles of functions availables with OpenCL 2.x . **A classic solution is to perform this final reduction with CPU but ideally, I would like to do it directly with kernel code**.

A suggestion of code snippet is welcome.

A last point, I am working on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.5 with the following model :

[image: model hardware]

Can OpenCL 2.x be installed on my hardware MacOS model ?

Comment: No. Apple does not support anything past OpenCL 1.2. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atomic functions should be avoided because they do harm performance compared to a parallel reduction kernel.  Your kernel looks to be on the right track, but you need to remember that you'll have to invoke it multiple times; do not perform the final sum on the host (unless you have a very small amount of data from the previous reduction).  That is, you need to keep invoking it until your local size equals your global size.  There's no way to do a single invocation for large amounts of data as there is no way to synchronize between work groups.

Additionally, you want to be careful to set an appropriate work group size (i.e. local size), which depends on local & global memory throughput & latency.  Unfortunately, as far as I'm aware there is no way to determine this through OpenCL, outside of self-profiling code, though that's not too difficult to write as OCL provides you with JIT compilation.  Through empirical testing I've found you should find a sweet spot between suffering too many bank conflicts (too large a local size) vs. global memory latency penalties (too small a local size).  It's best to do a benchmark first to determine optimal local size for your reduction, and then use that local size for future reductions.

**Edit:** It's also worth noting that the best way to chain your kernel invocation together is through OpenCL events.

Comment: Nice and thorough answer! Could you elaborate on the edit? Why is it faster to use events instead of just enqueuing multiple kernels consecutively in a in-order queue?